# Custom template delimiter for kataras/iris framework, Go Language

Tags: angularjs, go, go-iris

How do I add a custom delimiter to iris templates? I'm using angularjs for the front end and it conflicts with what angularjs is doing. I found some reference [here](https://github.com/kataras/iris/issues/71) but when I tried, it doesn't work, looks like the author of iris just gave a simple snippet just to describe it.

I'm quite new to Go so even checking the source code of `iris`, I'm having trouble. Thanks.

***Note: I know that I should be using static files for this, but this just really peaked my curiousity***

Comment: it might be easier to change the interpolation symbols in angular.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider#!/

Comment: Hahaha cool! I actually tried searching on how to do that but I don't know the keywords to type for angularjs (noobie as well). Thanks.